# Why should I specify a wrap element: <div> or <React.Fragment> or <> in JSX returns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see React raises errors when returning JSX codes for multiple elements, so it requires to always wrap those elements using these 3 options:

```
<>
<React.Fragment>
<div>
```

e.g. this one works:

```
const myReactComponent = () => {
   return (
     <div>
       <div>Div 1</div>
       <div>Div 2</div>
     </div>
   )
}
```

instead of:

```
const myReactComponent = () => {
   return (
       <div>Div 1</div>
       <div>Div 2</div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Your tree needs a single root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple
>   elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding
>   extra nodes to the DOM.

Which means React expects a single root element like a single `<div></div>`

Now if you use multiple `<div></div>` this is not actually expected by React, to eliminate this problem React introduces `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` or in short form `<></>` and this will enable you to group multiple child components within a single `<div></div>` that is already decleared in App component on in your parent component.

Answer (score 2):

JSX is compiled down to `React.createElement()`.

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

is equivalent to

```js
React.createElement('div', 'Test');
```

Since `React.createElement()` only creates a single element which is required by the component, JSX expressions must have one element.